# Display text file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, text, syntax

What code should I use to display the contents of a plain-text .txt file in JavaScript? I want the text to scroll on screen in the active window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As Patrick asked; the most important question is: Where is the text file?

Comment: Sorry for not including that, the file is server-side.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535125/display-text-file-in-htm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the text to display with new lines etc, use a `<pre>` or a `<textarea>`, i.e.

```
<pre id="contents"></pre>
```

Next is, where is the plain text file?

### From a Server

Use [*XMLHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```
function populatePre(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('contents').textContent = this.responseText;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}
populatePre('path/to/file.txt');
```

### From the local machine

Make the user select the file using an `<input type="file" />`

```
<input type="file" id="filechoice" />
```

Then when the user selects a file, use [*FileReader*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to populate the `<pre>`

```
document
    .getElementById('filechoice')
    .addEventListener(
        'change',
        function () {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('contents').textContent = this.result;
            };
            fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use below code for this purpose:

```
<iframe src="http://dev.imaginestudios.cu.cc/test.txt"></iframe>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/58aLua8b/1/)

Ref: [Display text file in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535125/display-text-file-in-html)

Comment: I don't think that's what it was asked in the question. It was said “display the contents of a plain-text .txt file **in JavaScript**”.