# show text from file into html webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am completely new in html and javascripts. what i am trying to do is fairly simple i think. I have a file hosted on a server and i want to show the text in the file on the page. I am following the answer for this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933085/display-text-file-in-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top).

However the text doesn't show at all.

```
<section>
<pre id="contents"></pre>
<script>function populatePre(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('contents').textContent = this.responseText;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}
 populatePre(${summary}); 
</script>
</section>
```

> ${summary} just contains the url for the text file

i've tried switching variable with the actual url no change

here's the url 
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mecturkaudiofiles/Order/20140707_tmm_pistorius_update_att.txt

I don't have to do it using javascript i just want to find a way that works

P.s. I've also tried

```
 <?php
echo file_get_contents("https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mecturkaudiofiles/Order/20140707_tmm_pistorius_update_att.txt");
?>
```

this is what i get as an output
[image: This is the preview of the output]

Comment: php, `file_get_contents()` easy approach

Comment: "P.s. I've also tried " you haven't told us whats wrong with that

Comment: Nothing shows up on the webpage. also tried that on online html editor same thing

Comment: You know that you can't make cross-domain ajax calls?

Comment: As i said i am pretty new to this so knowledge base is almost non-existent.
what can i do instead?!

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you `.open()`:

```
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 0) {
    console.log(xhr.response)
};
```

and remove the whole `xhr.onLoad` line

EDIT:
to populate the contents, instead of my console.log, use your:

```
document.getElementById('contents').textContent = xhr.response;
```

Comment: still not working. the pre area is loaded but it's empty

Comment: same issue. i think i might be missing something very trivial. i've attached a pic of the part where the text should be

Comment: What does your console say when you console log the response?

Comment: The brackets are unmatched
Expected ')' instead found populatePre