# Use XMLHttpRequest request to Display SELECTED Part of Plain Text File in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, text, import

I am hoping someone will be able to assist.  I'm very new to java etc however have managed via Google to learn plenty! :)

**Here's what I'm CURRENTLY Doing.**

I'm reading a server side (same domain etc) plain text file and loading the contents into a HTML page using XMLHttpRequest.  I use this approach as styles / formatting can be applied to the imported plain text.

The plain text file currently contains meeting dates for a **single** group (there are 30+ groups), this is generated by another local system and is to be uploaded to the server once per week.   When the Groups web page loads, it then loads the appropriate groups meeting text file and displays the results.  During testing this works fine.  This is a base example of what I used for testing (posted by Paul S [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933085/display-text-file-in-javascript) in 2013) and it works **100%** fine for loading and displaying the text file on page load (there's additional CSS etc not shown):

```
<!--  Load Group X Meetings -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 function populatePre(url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.onload = function () {
           document.getElementById('Meetings').textContent = this.responseText;
           };
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     xhr.send();
 }
 populatePre('/meeting-assets/group1meetings.txt');
</script>

<div>
    <pre id="Meetings" </pre>
</div>
```

An example of current plain text file format for **each group** is like this:

```
Mon, xxth Sep 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Sep 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Sep 2017 01:00 PM
Mon, xxth Oct 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Oct 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Oct 2017 01:00 PM
```

**WHAT I'D LIKE TO DO**

As outlined there are currently 30+ groups, each have 15+ future meeting dates scheduled, so this would require 30+ files being generated and uploaded.

IDEALLY ... I'd like to only upload a **single MASTER text file** that contains meetings for all Groups and use the same script on each web page but use a variable in the script to display only the meetings for the required Group.  I have complete control over how the text file is generated.

An example of what COULD be generated in the MASTER text file for **ALL GROUPS** could be SOMETHING this (but anything is possible - each group has a unique part of the name like "PAULS" and a constant like "GROUP"):

```
PAULS GROUP     
Mon, xxth Sep 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Sep 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Sep 2017 01:00 PM
Mon, xxth Oct 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Oct 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Oct 2017 01:00 PM
JENNYS GROUP    
Mon, xxth Sep 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Sep 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Sep 2017 01:00 PM
Mon, xxth Oct 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Oct 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Oct 2017 01:00 PM
JOHNS GROUP    
Mon, xxth Sep 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Sep 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Sep 2017 01:00 PM
Mon, xxth Oct 2017 03:00 PM
Wed, xxth Oct 2017 03:30 PM
Fri, xxth Oct 2017 01:00 PM
```

- Only "known" Groups would be fetched from the text file
- Each web page is dedicated to a Known Group and displays relevant info
  related to the Group.
- Ideally I'd like to duplicate /use the **same script** on each page and only change a single variable to fetch the right Group info.
- I have control over web page content and can insert scripts / code etc
- The pages are HTML generated pages on a hosted environment to which I have Cpanel access etc but not root admin? control?

The question.... 
How can I open the text file, read and populate/display the text/meeting dates of a **required group** onto the Groups web page? Is this possible, if so any ideas how I'd go about this?

I've attempted to provide clear info, let me know if more is required.  Any guidance / assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Boris :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, people use JSON formatted file for similar purposes to what you require.

Should you have a file named groupmeetings.json on the server formatted as such:

```
{
  "PAULS GROUP":[
   "Mon, xxth Sep 2017 03:00 PM",
   "Wed, xxth Sep 2017 03:30 PM",
  ],
  "JOHNS GROUP":[
   "Mon, xxth Sep 2017 03:00 PM",
   "Wed, xxth Sep 2017 03:30 PM",
 ]
}
```

You would then be able to use XmlHttpRequest to retrieve the JSON file from the server, parse it into a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse()` and access each persons groups within the object e.g `parsedJSON["JOHNS GROUP"]` would give you a list of future meetings for John.

Heres an idea  of what the script on each page may look like:

```
   function populatePre(url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.onload = function () {
            var groupMeetingsJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var johnsGroupMeetings = groupMeetingsJSON["JOHNS GROUP"]
            johnsGroupMeetings.forEach(function(scheduledMeeting){
               var div = document.createElement('div');
               div.innerHTML = scheduledMeeting.trim().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'');
               document.getElementById('Meetings').appendChild(div);
            });
           };
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     xhr.send();
 }


populatePre('/meeting-assets/groupmeetings.json');
```

Another alternative, is to obviously deduce some kind of separator in a plain text file between each of the groups. You will have to have a way to logically deduce the start and end of each group. This could simply be whenever a new group heading is found within the text file. When you receive the plain text file you will have to ignore the rest of the text file and find the portion that is meaningful for a particular groups page.

Comment: Awesome Eladian... a great starting point, tomorrow I'll look generating a test JSON data file with the suggested format and attempt to drop the right Group info onto a test page if I can work out how the script will look !!  As outlined I have complete control over how the data file is assembled so this could be perfect if I can get the script working!  Cheers for the pointer!!

Comment: No problem, I have also updated my response to include an idea of what the script on each page will look like. Good luck!

Comment: Eladian,awesome getting me going! I generated a test JSON file and trialed your script as above. INITIALLY nothing displayed as I was getting a parse error, I wrapped each element in " rather than a ' and it worked!  HOWEVER when displaying the results there is a load of PRECEDING spaces before the results.  The raw <pre> returns approx 8 lines of 24 spaces THEN the results, If I wrap the <pre> within in a simple  <div>  </div> I get a SINGLE preceding line of 24 spaces THEN the results.If I add CSS styling I get a 2 CR's, 60 spaces THEN the results. I've tried +,-,changing data - no effect.

Comment: Is this because each result is in a paragraph element? you could change the script to document.createElement('div') and see if that makes a difference ! Ill update the code

Comment: Updated code, if you wanted them on one line you could also use span instead. Not sure where any other whitespace would be coming from though! Would have to see the html structure

Comment: Eladian - 100% a winner!  I DID find an issue with my code ... I was not closing the  <pre id="Meetings">   with a ">" !! Duh! It is 1am here in NZ! :)  Even with that fixed there WAS a preceding space in the result.  Your trim fix and change to the div worked 100%!  AMAZING ASSISTANCE!  I am super grateful and appreciate your effort!  I don't have enough reputation to UP your solution, so hopefully someone that does will do it for me in spades!  Cheers again - Boris!

Comment: Haha no worries, happy to help a fellow kiwi out :) Glad you got it sussed. I think you should be able to mark the answer as accepted which would help me out :)