# JavaScript read txt file and show in html

Tags: javascript, html, express

So what I have is site made in expressjs, css, html and have txt file with scraped urls for images. I need some script for reading txt file and showing in html like card by card.

Like videos on this site stafty.xyz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display text file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933085/display-text-file-in-javascript)

Comment: Can be, I need it shown in div card by card like videos on thisbsite stafty.xyz

Comment: Maybe the FileReader API could work for you https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Its not that important for reading files than presenting in html

Comment: You can for sure represent the contents of a file with FileReader.